# c: Struct type incompatiable error

Tags: c, struct

my code as follows:

here I declare the publicgroup that after "struct group":

When I try to use the method, there is an error"struct group is incompatible with parameters of type struct group". I am using VS2013.

The error is in "int value = isgroupCointainsPID(publicgroup, 300);"This is the screen shot in my VS:
[image]

The strang thing is that if I ust the commented "test", it works well.

I am not quite sure ,what's wrong about my code?

```
struct proNode{
    int pID;
    struct proNode *next;

};
char groups [3][128];
struct group{
    int gID;
    char *name;
    struct proNode *prolist;
    struct proNode *blacklist;
}publicgroup;


int isgroupCointainsPID(struct group _group, int pID){
    if (_group.prolist == NULL){
        printf("There is no process %d\n", pID);
        return 0;
    }
    struct proNode *pros = _group.prolist;
    while (pros != NULL){
        if (pros->pID == pID)
            return 1;
        pros = pros->next;

    }
    printf("There is no process %d\n", pID);

    return 0;
}

int main(){
    publicgroup.gID = -1;
    publicgroup.name = "public group";
    publicgroup.prolist = NULL;
    publicgroup.blacklist = NULL;
    publicgroup.gID = 2;
// there is an error :struct group is incompatible with parameters of type struct group
    int value = isgroupCointainsPID(publicgroup, 300);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: How is `publicgroup` declared?

Comment: publicgroup is declared after the "struct group"

Comment: You're showing us two partial source files with no real indication of how they're connected. When I combine them into a single file and add `#include <stdio.h>` to the top, it compiles without error. Can you reduce the problem to a single source file?

Comment: This code is still not the code giving the error. Narrow down the problem to a _complete_ example reproducing the error (see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)). For starters: Copy your source file and start removing everything irrelevant. For example, most fields in the structure are probably unnecessary; the body of `isgroupContainsPID` can probably be changed to a simple `return 0;`. Make sure that none of these removals of code introduce new errors, but still reproduce the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incompatible parameters error is possible when you miss the function prototype. So please check whether you written the function prototype or not

Comment: yest, I add the function prototype :int isgroupCointainsPID(struct group _group, int pID); Then the problem is solved

Answer (score -1):

i guest you wrong when typing that method paramaters,
i never use VS so i cant give much advice,
i guest you want scan that usergroup, so you want pass it as pointer?
As i know when i use codeblocks, just try to change this

```
isgroupCointainsPID(struct group _group, int pID)
```

to

```
isgroupCointainsPID(group _group, int pID)
```

i hope its work

Comment: No, the name of the type is `struct group`, not just `group`. You can only refer to it as `group` if (a) you have a `typedef`, or (b) you'r programming in C++.